# Объекты Google Table из HTML

Tags: html

В макросе проверяю таблицу на пустые ячейки. Результат, список номеров строк, вывожу на окно в виде меню
ui.showModelessDialog(htm, "Пустые ячейки")

При нажатии на опцию меню мне надо сделать перемещение по таблице
sheet.setCurrentCell(cell)

Однако объекты таблицы из HTML не видны. Т.е. мне надо из JS скрипта
вызвать функцию на стороне Google Apps Script. По идее для этого есть
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler.
Но не работает. Как решить эту проблему ?